# Bootstrap 3 fluid well height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The following code accomplishes what I want ([JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqw43/)):

**HTML**

```
<div class="well">
  <div>
    <p>Really long text...</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
    </span>
  </input>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.well div {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

But I want to do it without specify the height, so that the well will always take up the remaining height of the screen. Is there a way to do this without Javascript?

**Edit:** Adding an image of what I eventually want to do, to provide context to the problem I'm trying to solve:

[image: Chat application mockup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/jiantongc/uqw43/2/

```
div.well {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom:40px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.user-input{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: I added an image to the question so you can see the responsiveness I want. This will be fine in the mobile view, but when it comes to the desktop view I won't be able to have it to the left of the list of people in a chat room.

Comment: Of course you can, just use the same concept... although I'm not a big fan of absolute positioning...http://jsfiddle.net/jiantongc/uqw43/4/, also see me old fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jiantongc/7uVNN/